# Send PDf attachment via sql email

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to send pdf attachments in sql email (sql server 2008). Sometimes the attachment is present in the emails , but its corrupt and cannot be opened. Sometime email itself is not going. When I try the same without adding the attachment, emails goes everytime. The attached file is hardly 300 KB and is present in teh server always.

Below is the code which ia m using to send emails.

```
  EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail                                                                                      
  @profile_name = @Profile,                                                                                     
  @recipients = @EmailTo,                        
  @copy_recipients = '',                                                                
  @subject = @EmailSubject,                                                                                      
  @body = @EmailBody,  
  @file_attachments = @Attachment,-- this will contain the physical file of teh document in database server.                                                                               
  @body_format = 'HTML',                                                                                      
  @execute_query_database = 'DBNAME'
```

I am not able to zero in as to what the issue is.

Comment: The problem is almost certainly not in the code you posted here but in the code that is used to populate @Attachment, or possibly in the data that created that data in the first place.

Comment: @Attachment is nothing but this will contain the physical file of teh document in database server. This is not created programitically. This is a manually created PDF and I can open this PDF as well seperately , so I dont see any issue with the PDF as such

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the files that are corrupt after being sent are not corrupt as they sit in the folder? I don't know how to help here as it would be nearly impossible to recreate this issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sql mail config had a limit of size of the attachments, hence the error was coming up. Anyways Thanks for your inputs